# Homebrew に対応するためインストールした Curl コマンドが認識されない

Tags: linux, homebrew, curl

xserver上にbrewをインストールしました。
`brew doctor` にて正常に動作しているか確かめたところ、下記のエラーが発生しました。

```
Error: Please update your system curl.
Minimum required version: 7.41.0
Your curl version: 7.29.0
Your curl executable: /usr/bin/curl
Error: Please update your system Git.
Minimum required version: 2.7.0
Your Git version: 1.8.3.1
Your Git executable: /usr/bin/git
```

どうやらcurlとGitのバージョンが古いとのことなので、ひとまずはcurlのバージョンを7.74.0に上げ、実際にバージョンアップできていることを確認しました。

```
$ ~/opt/bin/curl --version
curl 7.74.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.74.0 zlib/1.2.7
Release-Date: 2020-12-09
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap mqtt pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS Largefile libz UnixSockets
```

xserverでは、サーバ標準の古いバージョン(7.29.0)のcurlが強制的に参照されるとのことなので、下記記事を参照して、.bash_profileの内容を変更・sourceにて設定を反映させて自分がインストールしたcurlを参照できるようにしました。

[自分がインストールしたBrewを使うように変更する方法](https://book.studio947.net/article/4586/)

変更後の.bash_profileを下記に示します。

```sh
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

PATH=$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH

export PATH
export HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL="1"
```

しかしながら、再び `brew doctor` を行っても下記のエラーメッセージが出力されて、xserverの古いバージョンのcurlが参照されてしまいます。

```
$ brew doctor
Error: Please update your system curl.
Minimum required version: 7.41.0
Your curl version: 7.29.0
Your curl executable: /usr/bin/curl
Error: Please update your system Git.
Minimum required version: 2.7.0
Your Git version: 1.8.3.1
Your Git executable: /usr/bin/git
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Some installed formulae are deprecated or disabled.
You should find replacements for the following formulae:
  isl@0.18

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /home/[xserverID]/opt/bin/curl-config

Warning: An outdated version (1.8.3.1) of Git was detected in your PATH.
Git 2.7.0 or newer is required for Homebrew.
Please upgrade:
  brew install git

Warning: Your Homebrew's prefix is not /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew.
Some of Homebrew's bottles (binary packages) can only be used with the default
prefix (/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew).
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
unsupported configuration.
```

どのようにすれば、自分がインストールしたcurlをbrewが参照できるようになるのでしょうか？教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` とされていますが、brew でインストールした curl のファイルパスは `~/opt/bin/curl` なので、`PATH=$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH` とする必要があるかと思います。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。curlのファイルパスを.bash_profileに記載し、brew doctorを実施したところ、質問欄と同様のエラーメッセージ(古いバージョンのcurlを参照)が出力されてしまいます。現状の.bash_profileの設定を質問欄に反映いたしました。

Comment: 念のために確認しますが `source ~/.bash_profile` は実行しましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。実行していますがエラーのままです。

Comment: 念のため一旦ログインし直した後で、`which curl` を実行して自分のインストールした Curl のパスを参照しているかをまず確認してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bash_profile` における環境変数 `PATH` の設定(`export PATH=$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH`)が効かないのは brew コマンド(シェルスクリプト)の内部で `PATH` がリセットされているためです。

[brew/brew at master · Homebrew/brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/bin/brew#L104)

```sh
if [[ -z "${HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING}" ]]
then
  PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

  FILTERED_ENV=()
  # Filter all but the specific variables.
  for VAR in HOME SHELL PATH ...
  do
              :

    FILTERED_ENV+=( "${VAR}=${!VAR}" )
  done

  exec /usr/bin/env -i "${FILTERED_ENV[@]}" /bin/bash "${HOMEBREW_LIBRARY}/Homebrew/brew.sh" "$@"
```

次に、brew コマンドで exec されている `brew.sh` では以下の様な処理が行われています。

[brew/brew.sh at master · Homebrew/brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh#L283)

```sh
if [[ -n "${HOMEBREW_FORCE_BREWED_CURL}" &&
      -x "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/curl/bin/curl" ]] &&
         "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/curl/bin/curl" --version >/dev/null
then
  HOMEBREW_CURL="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/curl/bin/curl"
elif [[ -n "${HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER}" && -x "${HOMEBREW_CURL_PATH}" ]]
then
  HOMEBREW_CURL="${HOMEBREW_CURL_PATH}"
else
  HOMEBREW_CURL="curl"
fi
```

質問文では curl コマンドのファイルパスは `~/opt/bin/curl` となっていますので、`HOMEBREW_CURL` は `curl` にセットされます。`PATH` は `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` にリセットされていますので、最終的に `HOMEBREW_CURL` の値は `/usr/bin/curl` になります。

これを回避して `HOMEBREW_CURL` に `$HOME/opt/bin/curl` をセットするためには `~/.bash_profile` に以下を追加すればよいかと思います。

```sh
export HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER=1
export HOMEBREW_CURL_PATH="$HOME/opt/bin/curl"
```